# PowerShell Script "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument"?

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to run a script that is as follows (to find and uninstall CCleaner):

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq "CCleaner"} -OutVariable Results **{
& "$($Results.InstallLocation)\uninst.exe"
}
```

The error is:

```
Where-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 
& "$($Results.InstallLocation)\uninst.exe" /S
.At line:1 char:98
+ Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object <<<<  {$_.DisplayName -eq "CCleaner"} -OutVariable Results {
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
```

The last part there seems to be a problem. I am sure this is because I am writing this in PS v3 but I'm running this as a PSSession on PC's running PS v2 or v1.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq "CCleaner"} | ForEach-Object { & "$($_.InstallLocation)\uninst.exe" }
```

Otherwise, you need to use a named parameter after "Results"

Comment: I really appreciate the advice. So, it seems as thought the script will run now without an error. However, when I run the first part:

Comment: Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq "CCleaner"}

Comment: It still shows the program CCleaner installed? By the way sorry for the multiple comments!

Comment: I can't speak for the specifics of CCleaner, perhaps there are command line parameters? Have you tried executing uninst.exe from a command prompt?

Comment: Try using:
. "$($_.InstallLocation)\uninst.exe"
To capture the output